# How to run owasp zap in a sequential order and is it possible to do parametrization in owaps zap

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using OWASP ZAP and i have 2 urls namely A and B and these URL should be passed like A,B as first request and second request A,B.if this order goes wrong i get privilage error which ultimately fails my test as owasp zap wont be able to deliver result properly.

Could someone help me on how to execute it sequentially.\

I referred the https://zapmultistep.wordpress.com/ but unfortunately it doesnt help.could anyone help me understand in detail.

Is it possible to do parametrization in owasp zap ,if so could you please explain in detail

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/sHYVplza32w/VOiQRILaAgAJ for an ongoing discussing about these questions.